# Rails application that includes a PHP page

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

This is a 2 part question:

a. Is it possible to have a .php file as a view in Rails? Need it because at some point some data needs to be signed with a bank provided function -only in PHP-

```
<?php
   $base64 = ".SignData("some data from rails", "private.key.pem")
?>
```

I tried in Rails something like:

..
render file "/home/myApp/app/view/signData.php.erb"
..

Also tried

..

render file "/home/myApp/app/view/signData.php"

..

But tells me "Template is missing". I know it is not a matter of path because if change .php to .html in path, it finds the file.

b. The other question: how to get back to rails the $base64 info obtained in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Call the PHP script from the command line? Or use a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about having your web server reroute that one specific call to PHP instead of Rails? It might be the cleanest solution. Something like http://weblog.terrellrussell.com/2008/01/running-php-within-rails/.

Comment: Thanks JoshEmory! I was unable to see terrell... Seems like server is down because have tried several times.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a separate, small PHP webservice to wrap this SignData method. You can host it on the same platform, which is handy, then call it from your main application with some straight forward Net::HTTP.